# Can't Open Billing Account on GCP for Dialogflow - "You can’t reopen this billing account because this account is not in good standing"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, error-handling, dialogflow-es, subscription, billing

I'm trying to subscribe to Google Cloud Platform (GCP) to use Dialogflow in my project. However, I'm encountering an error that says, "You can’t reopen this billing account because this account is not in good standing." when I enter my card details. The strange thing is that the amount is deducted from my account, and I receive a bank message on my phone.

I've already tried multiple cards, including credit and debit, and created accounts with different emails. I've also asked friends to create accounts for me, but I keep getting the same error message.

[Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Imf8.png)[Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX6Wu.png)

Comment: You must contact Google Cloud Billing support. Stack Overflow cannot help you with billing or financial problems. https://cloud.google.com/support/billing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i did not understad what i had to do.

After some digging in found out that in overview/payment overview it did show why my billing account was suspended.

[image: payment overview]

Answer (score 0):

please check if you have done any of the things in  `Account settings that you cannot modify` section in the below page:

https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-billing-account

I do not know how it might be connected to your case, but I had same error and I realized that the the issue is raised because I removed the connected payments profile and seems it can not be undone.
[image]

I hope it can give you some hints to root the cause.